# Custom discrete gesture recognizers able to send several discrete actions and respond to requireGestureRecognizerToFail requirements

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I have encountered some problems with custom gesture recognition. I am trying to do something that is slightly different from the general use-case of the UIGestureRecognizer implementation.

### More specifically

- I have discrete gestures, but I want them to send several messages at specific points during the gesture (eg. I have a "loops" gesture, and I want to send a `newLoopRecognized` message each time there is a new loop, and a `allLoopsRecognized` message at the end of the gesture)
- I want to be able to "reset" the gesture state after some messages, but to allow the gesture recognizer to still receive events (and not have to remove all touches, & start the gesture all over: each time I send the `newLoopRecognized` message, I want to be able to draw new loops without lifting my finger and starting again, which is not possible if I switch to the `GestureRecognized` state)
- I want to have several gestures that can require other gesture recognizers to fail

What I understand is that when you are drawing a continuous gesture, the action message will be sent to the target object **at a regular interval**, and not necessarily each time you change your state from `StateChanged` to `StateChanged` again?

Thus this wouldn't work in my case, since I want to send events only at some specific event (the start of a new loop).

Also, if I used the continuous gesture approach, I wouldn't be able to do reset my state between each successive loop by:

```
...
if( new_loop_detected )
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
    [self reset];
}
...
```

since this would preclude me from extracting the state of the loop (for instance velocity & amplitude) in the `newLoopRecognized` message because they are reset before the message is sent.

I could use a convoluted approach such as copying all my state variables in another variable that I would use in the `newLoopRecognized` message, but this would be messy.

I could simply send my notification messages in the code, such as :

```
...
if( new_loop_detected )
{
    [self performSelector:actionOnNewLoopRecognized onTarget:target];
}
...
```

but this would fire those message events even if I set `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` on another gesture recognizer to allow this one to make detections, and the other had not yet had time to fail or be recognized.

### Possible design

If there is no easy way to implement my design with the regular UIGestureRecognizer implementation, I would probably have to extend the discrete gesture states

```
StatePossible -> StateRecognizing -> StateRecognized
```

where transitionning to StateRecognizing would:

- send the correct action message (for instance I have an additional state variable that I set to `MessageIsOnNewLoopRecognized` or `MessageIsOnAllLoopsRecognized`) and call reset on the gesture recognizer
- preclude gesture recognizers that require this gesture recognizer to fail to make a detection

### Question

Is there a way to use the regular UIGestureRecognizer subclassing to do what I want, or should I reimplement the whole gesture recognition framework? Are there suitable examples of such implementations, or do you have an idea what would be the proper design? If I were to reimplement the complete gesture framework, I'd like it to be backward-compatible with regular gestures to allow me to use the iOS gestures without reimplementing them.